# Troubleshooting authors / language options in Jekyll / GitHub Pages + Prose

Tags: github, jekyll

I have recently started a project using Jekyll/GitHub pages. I edit the docs locally and push the changes to this repo : 
https://github.com/piapandelakis/piapandelakis.github.io

I use the Skinny Bones template.

I have made two edits that don't show up, either locally or on github pages.

- I have created an authors.yml doc, and edited the front matter of my post accordingly ; but the name displayed is still "pia_pandelakis" (short version) instead of "Pia Pandelakis". This site is intented to be multi-authors so it's quite bothering...
- I have switched the langage in _config.yml from "locale: en" to "locale: fr". However the dates and details of the template still appear in english and not in french.

At first I was only working locally and assumed this was a matter of the _config.yml not reloading properly, despite my several attempts to kill the jekyll process and reload it. I removed the "exclude" line, tried different approaches, and checked that Xcode, gems, etc. was up to date.

Since then I have started the project afresh with a github repo and githubpages, but the end result is the same, locally or on the server.
If anyone has any ideas concerning these two issues, I would appreciate it. I have already scouted several forums to find a solution but I'm pretty much in a dead end here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print author for a post : `<span itemprop="name">{{ site.data.authors[page.author].name }}</span>`

For the date, it's not a question of locale. Jekyll date are formated by filters.
Currently, you use `{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}` ([see ruby documentation for date formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)).

If you want to output your date the french way you can use the following include (`_includes/pagedate.html`):

```
{% comment %}
  # Use in a loop
  {% for post in site.post %}
    {% include pagedate.html date=post.date %}
  {% endfor %}

  # Use in a page template
  {% include pagedate.html %}
{% endcomment %}

{% assign date = include.date %}
{% if date == nil %}
  {% assign date = page.date %}
{% endif %}

{% assign m = date | date: "%-m" %}
{{ date | date: "%-d" }}
{% case m %}
  {% when '1' %}Janvier
  {% when '2' %}Février
  {% when '3' %}Mars
  {% when '4' %}Avril
  {% when '5' %}Mai
  {% when '6' %}Juin
  {% when '7' %}Juillet
  {% when '8' %}Août
  {% when '9' %}Septembre
  {% when '10' %}Octobre
  {% when '11' %}Novembre
  {% when '12' %}Décembre
{% endcase %}
{{ date | date: "%Y" }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David for this! I have followed your instructions for issue #1 regarding the author name printing, and it worked perfectly. As for the date, it didn't work for some reason (I tried different things, but no luck...). I realized however the rest of the website was correctly translated.. so I just switched to a different date formatting system squeezing the name of the month altogether... thanks again for a very detailed reply :-)